# WPF application crashed after user exit from CMD full screen mode

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-xp, cmd

WPF application crashed after user exit from CMD full screen mode.
I have not any idea to fix it, here is the exception:

```
e.Exception
{"An unspecified error occurred on the render thread."}
    [System.InvalidOperationException]: {"An unspecified error occurred on the render thread."}
    _className: null
    _data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    _dynamicMethods: null
    _exceptionMethod: null
    _exceptionMethodString: null
    _helpURL: null
    _HResult: -2146233079
    _innerException: null
    _message: "An unspecified error occurred on the render thread."
    _remoteStackIndex: 0
    _remoteStackTraceString: null
    _source: "PresentationCore"
    _stackTrace: {sbyte[192]}
    _stackTraceString: null
    _xcode: -532459699
    _xptrs: 0
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    HResult: -2146233079
    InnerException: null
    IsTransient: false
    Message: "An unspecified error occurred on the render thread."
    Source: "PresentationCore"
    StackTrace: "   
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.NotifyPartitionIsZombie(Int32 failureCode)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.NotifyChannelMessage()\r\n   
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n   
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n   
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)\r\n   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)"
    TargetSite: {Void NotifyPartitionIsZombie(Int32)}
```

Comment: Can you provide enough source for us to recreate the problem?  We can help you better if you do.

Comment: i am sorry i can't provide all application source code, and i don't know which code made this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in .NET 3.5 SP1 I believe - make sure you have all of the latest updates and install anything in Windows Update related to .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your response. our machine has already installed .NET 3.5 SP1. we don't check all updates related to .NET, do you know which update will fix this?